# Questions about Disconnected-RNN (published in ACL 2018)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, acl

In ACL 2018, an interesting architecture called disconnected-RNN was proposed. It could be regarded as a special 1D CNN where convolution kernels are replaced with recurrent units. The paper is at http://aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1215 . However, when I try to reproduce the model, I could not get good results, it is always worse than Conv1D or GRU. My implementation is at https://github.com/zepingyu0512/disconnected-rnn ,written in keras-tensorflow. Maybe my code is wrong or the parameters need to be tuned, so please help if interested.

Comment: Please consider narrowing down the scope of your question. Right now, you are asking people to understand a scientific paper, then look at *all* of your code, and then say "yup, here is your mistake". Instead, please create a [mcve], where you describe the more specific problem (i.e., does not converge, bad accuracy, training fails, ...) and give a nice summary without pointing people to external sources.

Comment: I also implemented it using Tensorflow (https://github.com/GalaxyDream/DRNN-Tensorflow), got bad performance as well. I asked Baoxin for the code, but he said he could not provide it due to a contract with a company.